# Owned entity causing json serialization error in Google javascript api client

Tags: google-app-engine, jackson, google-api-client, google-cloud-endpoints

Getting error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

and

```
Caused by: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

Samples of my entities:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    public Key getKey() {return this.key;   }
    public User()   {}
    public Address getAddress() {return address;}
    public void setAddress(Address address) {this.address = address;}
    @Persistent
    private Address address;
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class Address {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
@Persistent
private String otherProperty;
//Also have the set and get
}
```

Using the google javascript api client tool (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/)

Connecting to Google cloud endpoint generated in eclipse.
-While using the api explorer, I can add users with addresses no problem(localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer).

When not using address, the call works as expected:

```
var request = gapi.client.userendpoint.user.insert({
firstName : "test",
lastName : "test",
emailAddress : "test",
phoneNumber : "test"
});
console.log(request);
request.execute(function(resp){console.log(resp);})
```

However when calling with address, it fails:

```
var request2 = gapi.client.userendpoint.user.insert({
firstName : "test",
lastName : "test",
emailAddress : "test",
clubName : "test",
ahaNumber : "test",
phoneNumber : "test",
address: {
attention : "test",
line1 : "test",
line2 : "test",
line3 : "test",
state : "test",
postalCode : "test",
country : "test"
}
});
console.log(request2);
request2.execute(function(resp){console.log(resp);})
```

with error:

```
POST http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/rpc 500 (Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token  at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1])
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Feel like I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Havent figured this out yet.  So i went with a jquery solution:  $.ajax({
  beforeSend: function (request) {
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");      
    },
     url: com.beer.registrar.endpoints.url.insert,
     type: 'POST',
     processData: false,
     data: JSON.stringify(user), 
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(resp) { console.log(resp);},
     failure: function(resp) { console.log("fail");console.log(resp);}
 });

Comment: Does the JSON differ between what you wrote and what JSON.stringify provides? How about between what your wrote and what's written in the APIs Explorer?

Comment: @user2130254 Did this resolve itself?

Comment: Can't really help without the raw Json that's generated... The error message tells you that it's expecting a Json string but instead receives a Json Object. So there's 2 possible cause: the generated JSON is not what you expect, or your class definition does not match the generated JSON.

Comment: I never figured this out.  Refactored it to do it a different way completely.  Can no longer get the raw JSON easily...