# Deserialization error using Google cloud endpoint JS api Client

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have set up a local appengine with endpoints. Using CURL I test the endponts succesfully like this:

```
C:\Program Files>curl.exe --header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{g:\"test\",u:1,l:{x:1,y:1}}" http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/myapp/v1/move
```

The response I get is as expected:

```
{
    "g" : "test",
    "u" : 1,
    "l" : {
        "x" : 1,
        "y" : 1
    }
}
```

When I go to my JS client and attempt to do the same, weird things start to happen. Apparently the nested element "l" fails to deserialize when calling the endpoint from Javascript. I wonder why that is?

This is the error message I get in the console:

```
500 (Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token  at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1])
```

Here's my JS function that calls my endpoint.

```
function init() {
    var myapp = 'http://localhost:8888/_ah/api';
    gapi.client.load('myapp', 'v1', function() {
        var payload = {g:"Test",u:0,l:{x:4,y:4}};
        gapi.client.myapp.unit.move(payload).execute(function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        });
    }, myapp);
}
```

The payload sent to the server is:

```
[{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"gapiRpc","method":"myapp.unit.move","params":{"g":"Test","u":0,"l":{"x":4,"y":4}},"apiVersion":"v1"}]
```

When I remove the `l:{x:4,y:4}` from the payload my endpoint gets called just fine.

Seems that I am doing something wrong but what?

See also
[Owned entity causing json serialization error in Google javascript api client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193944/owned-entity-causing-json-serialization-error-in-google-javascript-api-client)

Answer (score 1):

## Python:

This seems to be an issue with the Java backend, for Python endpoints, I implemented an API that uses a class called `Total` to hold the data:

```
from protorpc import messages

class LeftRight(messages.Message):
    x = messages.IntegerField(1)
    y = messages.IntegerField(2)

class Total(messages.Message):
    g = messages.StringField(1)
    u = messages.IntegerField(2)
    l = messages.MessageField(LeftRight, 3)
```

and then has a dummy Endpoint which just returns back the `Total` object it received

```
...
@endpoints.method(Total, Total,
                  path='total', http_method='POST',
                  name='total.total')
def total(self, request):
    return request
```

and it works perfectly using essentially the same Javascript you included.

I incorporated this into our sample application in a [branch](https://github.com/dhermes/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python/commit/3379df39e4dade254e89b50331a83023199b3989) I made in my fork. For the specifics, see the [commit](https://github.com/dhermes/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python/commits/stackoverflow-15461820). NOTE: I made a subsequent [commit](https://github.com/dhermes/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python/commit/257e3474de3d58c70572d450b87997681a878a9c) to get rid of Auth/https so it runs in `dev_appserver`.

## Java:

TBD